# what is definition of height function for subsurface?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, manifolds, surfaces

what is definition of  height function for subsurface ?

in the [paper](https://sci-hub.se/10.1515/crll.2000.028) :

" On the TeichmuÈ ller tower of mapping class
groups
By Allen Hatcher at Ithaca, Pierre Lochak at Paris and Leila Schneps."

we have :

" A picture of the subsurface with  $\pm f_{t u}$ as the **height function** is shown in figure  11
"

[image]

Comment: It usually just mean $(x, y, z)\mapsto z$. But without further information (I dont have assess to the paper) I am not sure.

Comment: @ArcticChar .what is height function  as in Morse theory ?

Comment: @ArcticChar . https://sci-hub.se/10.1515/crll.2000.028

Comment: The only place I find "height function" in the note is the sentence "A picture of the subsurface with $\pm f_{tu}$ as the height function is shown in figure 11". So I suppose it is $\pm f_{tu}$ where they refer to height function. In general it is just a morse function I suppose.